# How to get a list with filenames for last 30 days looking only at the filename string?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of filenames that looks like this:

```
myDailyUrls = ['https://myurl.com/something/something_01-09-2020.csv', 
'https://myurl.com/something/something_31-08-2020.csv'],
#and so on for entire year...]
```

How could I get a list of the 30 files with the newest dates?

The below will give me the filename with the newest date, however I'm looking for 30 files with newest dates:

```
dailyMax = max(myDailyUrls,
key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.split('_')[1].replace('.csv', ''), "%d-%m-%Y"))
```

Could someone help with this? thank you in advance!

Comment: Filenames aren't your problem, just the dates of the previous 30 days. What you do with them is unimportant. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Use `sorted()` on your list, with the same key you're using for `max()`, and then use a slice to take the last 30 elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dailyData = sorted(myDailyUrls,
key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.split('_')[1].replace('.csv', ''), "%d-%m-%Y"))
print(dailyData)
```

Output:

```
['https://myurl.com/something/something_31-08-2020.csv',
 'https://myurl.com/something/something_01-09-2020.csv']
```